# Taking Limit of a function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, proof-writing

I'm reading a proof and I don't understand one step.

```
1−(1−λ/n)^tn.
Now, taking the limit as n→∞,
P(Yn/n≤t)⟶1−e^(−λt).
```

How does that work out? In this case, t is time(in seconds), n is the number of Bernoulli(p) trials per second and Yn is the time until the first success.

Further, if this converges to an exponential as n -> infinity, why is this significant?

Comment: Probably typo, want $1-\frac{\lambda}{n}$, not $1-\lambda n$.

Comment: sorry,didn't see that

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1-\lambda / n)^n = e^{-\lambda}$,
so
$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1-\lambda / n)^{t n} = e^{-\lambda t}$.

Don't know if you also want a proof of the first limit or already know it.

This is significant because the exponential distribution
has many useful properties,
such as memory independence.
It is also simpler.
It also won the 2011 competition
as the distribution of the year.